# Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.util.Date to java.sql.Date

Tags: java, mysql, simpledateformat

I am trying to get my code to work with the SimpleDateFormat class here in the code. Does anybody knows why? Have a nice day from Julie

When I run the code where I have imported: import java.util.Date. I get the error: 
"The type Date is ambiguous" in the lines:

```
Date startDate = format.parse(req.getParameter("startDate")); 
Date endDate = format.parse(req.getParameter("endDate"));
```

When I run the code where I have imported: import java.sql.Date; I get the error:

```
Date startDate = format.parse(req.getParameter("startDate")); 
Date endDate = format.parse(req.getParameter("endDate"));
```

"Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.util.Date to java.sql.Date"

```
import java.sql.Date;

package WorkPackage;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Date.*;


    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) 
        throws ServletException, IOException{

        String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/NekiWork";
        Connection connection=null;
        //String startDate = req.getParameter("startDate");
        //String endDate= req.getParameter("endDate");

        try {
            //Load database driver
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            //Connection to the database
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", ""); 
            //Getting the data from database

            String sql = "SELECT *, (Day_hours + (Day_minutes / 60)) AS Allday_hours FROM Workdata "
                    + "WHERE Date = startdate = ? AND endDate = ? ";
            PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

            //Date startDate;

            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Date startDate = format.parse(req.getParameter("startDate")); 
            Date endDate = format.parse(req.getParameter("endDate"));
            pst.setDate(1,startDate);
            pst.setDate(2, endDate);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) and [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) are different. Database accepts only `java.sql.Date`.
For that, you need to convert `java.util.Date` into `java.sql.Date`.

Try this:

```
java.util.Date util_StartDate = format.parse( req.getParameter("startDate") );
java.sql.Date sql_StartDate = new java.sql.Date( util_StartDate.getTime() );
```

Now you can use this `sql_StartDate` to set parameter values using prepared statement.

```
pst.setDate( 1, sql_StartDate );
```

Use the same procedure on other sql specific dates to use with jdbc.

Answer (score 1):

Where you have both the `java.sql.*` and `java.util.*` namespaces imported, the compiler cannot uniquely determine a best type for the `Date` token. In this instance you can qualify your type with the namespace:

```
java.util.Date startDate = format.parse(req.getParameter("startDate"));
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. When I do this I get an error in my pst.setDate(1,startDate); where it says:

"The method setDate(int, java.sql.Date) in the type PreparedStatement is not applicable for the arguments (int, java.util.Date)"

Do you know why this is?

Answer (score -2):

```
Date fechaNace= new java.sql.Date(persona.getFechaNacimiento().getTime());
ps.setDate(6,(java.sql.Date) fechaNace);
```