# Insert Date in string format into a database having field type of Date

Tags: java, mysql, date, prepared-statement

I am having a date in the following format as string.

```
String from_date = "2016-09-09";
```

I need to insert into into a database having date type field using `PreparedStatement`. I have done it in the following way.

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date fd = formatter.parse(from_date);
select1.setDate(1, fd);
```

But it is showing the error as

> The method setDate(int.java.sql.Date) in the type PreparedStatement is not applicable to the arguments(int,java.util.Date)

Comment: `select1.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(fd.getTime()));`

Comment: thanks.. It worked :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a `java.sql.Date` when inserting in database. Try the following :

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date fd = formatter.parse(from_date);
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(fd.getTime());
select1.setDate(1, sqlDate);
```

Comment: when using getTime() will i get the date?

Comment: You will get the time in `long` which you use to create the new `java.sql.Date`. It is done in order to convert form `java.util.Date` to `java.sql.Date`.

Comment: @NicoVanBelle nice catch, I skipped that one :)

Answer (score 1):

Answered here: [Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.util.Date to java.sql.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22351434/type-mismatch-cannot-convert-from-java-util-date-to-java-sql-date)

You are trying to use a method that accepts `java.sql.Date` instead of `java.util.Date`

Welcome to programming, mind the details

Answer (score 1):

### Using java.sql.Date

#### java.util.Date

Suppose you have a variable endDate of type java.util.Date, you make the conversion thus:

```
 select1.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(endDate.getTime());
```