# How to get date from html form to servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I have an HTML form where I have a date and a time picker. What I am trying to do is get the date and time by `request.getParameter` in servlet, then insert it into my database. How can I get that date and time in date and time format or get them as a string then parse them.

Code:

```
String[] quantity = request.getParameterValues("Quantity_field");
     java.util.Date selectedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(request.getParameter("deliveryDate")); //using this one i am trying to get date but it is showing error
    java.util.Date selectedTime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss").parse(request.getParameter("deliveryTime")); 
    System.out.println(selectedDate);
    java.util.Date dateUtil = new Date();
    java.sql.Date dateSql = new java.sql.Date(dateUtil.getTime());
    java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(dateUtil.getTime());


    try {
        con = DBConnection.createConnection();
        statement = con.createStatement();
        String query = " insert query  VALUES   (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
        for (int i = 0; i < quantity.length; i++) {
            if (Double.parseDouble(quantity[i]) != 0) {
                if(recorderNo!=0)
                {
                    ps.setInt(1, recorderNo);
                }
                else
                {
                    ps.setInt(1, 1);
                }

                ps.setDate(2, dateSql);
                ps.setString(3, 77);
                ps.setDouble(4, 55);
                ps.setInt(5, 0);
                ps.setInt(6, 0);
                ps.setDouble(7, Double.parseDouble(quantity[i]));
                ps.setInt(8, 0);
                ps.setInt(9, 0);
                ps.setInt(10, 0);
                ps.setString(11, outlet);
                ps.setTimestamp(12, timestamp);
                 ps.setDate(13,selectedDate); // here i am trying to put date
                ps.setTime(14,selectedTime);// and here time
                ps.addBatch();
            }
        }
        ps.executeBatch();
```

I found this on Google to get date and time but its throwing error at:

```
ps.setDate(13,selectedDate);
ps.setTime(14,selectedTime);
```

The error is:

> The method setDate(int, java.sql.Date) in the type PreparedStatement is not applicable for the arguments (int, java.util.Date)

**Edit**

i am doing like this

```
java.util.Date selectedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(request.getParameter("deliveryDate")); 
    java.util.Date selectedTime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss").parse(request.getParameter("deliveryTime"));
    java.sql.Date dateSelected = new java.sql.Date(selectedDate.getTime());     
    java.sql.Time dateTime=new Time(selectedTime.getTime());
```

but the above lines are throwing error, i think i am missing something or writing something wrong

Comment: Change `java.util.Date` to `java.util.Date` Please refer to [Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.util.Date to java.sql.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22351434/type-mismatch-cannot-convert-from-java-util-date-to-java-sql-date)

Comment: Convert your dates to `java.sql.Date` like you did with `java.sql.Date dateSql = new java.sql.Date(dateUtil.getTime())` .

Comment: @Arnaud i have tried this but for time its throwing error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `java.util.Date selectedDate` is of `java.util.Date` type while PreparedStatement's `setDate(int, java.sql.Date)` method requires a `java.sql.Date` type. So convert your `java.util.Date` into `java.sql.Date`

You can add this lines:

```
java.util.Date selectedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(request.getParameter("deliveryDate")); 
java.util.Date selectedTime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss").parse(request.getParameter("deliveryTime")); 
// Add the lines below
java.sql.Date selectedSQLDate =  new java.sql.Date(selectedDate.getTime());
java.sql.Time selectedSQLTime =  new java.sql.Time(selectedTime.getTime());
```

So your code will be:

```
        // Other codes
 try { 
        String[] quantity = request.getParameterValues("Quantity_field");
        java.util.Date selectedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(request.getParameter("deliveryDate")); 
        java.util.Date selectedTime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss").parse(request.getParameter("deliveryTime")); 
        // Add the lines below
        java.sql.Date selectedSQLDate =  new java.sql.Date(selectedDate.getTime());
        java.sql.Time selectedSQLTime =  new java.sql.Time(selectedTime.getTime());
        con = DBConnection.createConnection();
        statement = con.createStatement();
        String query = " insert query  VALUES   (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
        for (int i = 0; i < quantity.length; i++) {
            if (Double.parseDouble(quantity[i]) != 0) {
                if(recorderNo!=0)
                {
                    ps.setInt(1, recorderNo);
                }
                else
                {
                    ps.setInt(1, 1);
                }

                ps.setDate(2, dateSql);
                ps.setString(3, 77);
                ps.setDouble(4, 55);
                ps.setInt(5, 0);
                ps.setInt(6, 0);
                ps.setDouble(7, Double.parseDouble(quantity[i]));
                ps.setInt(8, 0);
                ps.setInt(9, 0);
                ps.setInt(10, 0);
                ps.setString(11, outlet);
                ps.setTimestamp(12, timestamp);
                ps.setDate(13,selectedDate); // here i am trying to put date
                ps.setTime(14,selectedTime);// and here time
                ps.addBatch();
            }
        }
        ps.executeBatch();
        // Other codes

} catch (Exception e){
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
}
```

But I suggest you use `java.time` classes instead of legacy `java.util.Date` & `java.sql.Date` with JDBC 4.2 or later. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530012/how-to-convert-java-util-date-to-java-sql-date) for details.

Comment: hey i am doing the same by trying your answer this line `java.util.Date selectedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(request.getParameter("deliveryDate")); 
  java.util.Date selectedTime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss").parse(request.getParameter("deliveryTime"));`  is showing error as  `Unhandled exception type ParseException`

Comment: Place it inside your try-catch block

Answer (score 0):

You have two different Date objects (util.Date and sql.Date), so you need to convert from util.Date to sql.Date to use setDate method.

[Explanation in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530012/how-to-convert-java-util-date-to-java-sql-date)